# Errors when adapting an Angular application in Liferay

Tags: angular, liferay, liferay-dxp, liferay-7.2

I'm trying to adapt an Angular 10 application (a hello world application generated by Angular CLI) to run as a widget in Liferay 7.2 (using liferay-js:adapt).

When I deploy the jar the browser displays the following errors:

```
Error: The following problems where detected while resolving modules:
    · Missing dependency 'hello-world-app@0.0.0/hello-world-app/polyfills-es5' of 'hello-world-app@0.0.0/index'
    · Missing dependency 'hello-world-app@0.0.0/hello-world-app/runtime-es5' of 'hello-world-app@0.0.0/index'
    · Missing dependency 'hello-world-app@0.0.0/hello-world-app/main-es5' of 'hello-world-app@0.0.0/index'
```

Comment: Does the name of the folder including the angular app include spaces or uppercases? Have you checked this link (https://github.com/liferay/liferay-js-toolkit/commit/7b23b58d5dbac90cfc92b569111417db7d64c6bb)

Comment: yes I've already checked that, no way. By the way, I created about that a thread there in github and it still open.

Comment: Please check recent changed version 2.24.1 of generator-liferay-js it may fix this issue of missing dependency.